# "Couldn't modify partition map" and "MediaKit reports no such partition" when attempting to format partition

Tags: disk-utility, partition

I'm trying to create a storage partition on my bootable Linux flash drive (see [my other question on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/1371129/gparted-and-disk-utility-disagree-on-the-partition-layout-but-disk-utility-is)). I formatted my provisional partition FAT32 using GParted. The Mac saw it just fine, although I forgot to look whether it could read the test data *on* the partition.

But when I went to reformat the partition, it came back with "MediaKit reports no such partition". When I tried using the Partition dialog, it said "Couldn't modify partition map" instead.

Any idea what could be causing this or how to fix it, preferably without losing my Linux partition?

[image: using partition dialog]
[image: using single-partition erase button]